# IcCube - Get yesterday's Member in MDX Query

Tags: mdx, iccube

I have a Date Dimension looking like this `[date].[date].[day].[yyyy-MM-dd]` and I would like to get the member representing yesterday i.e. `[date].[date].[day].[2016-07-27]`. How can I accomplish this.

In some threads about MDX, but not IcCube specific, it is written like this:
1. `STRTOMEMBER("[date].[date].[day].["+ FORMAT(NOW()-1,"yyyy-MM-dd") +"]")`
2. `STRTOMEMBER("[date].[date].[day].["+ VBAMDX.FORMAT(VBAMDX.NOW()-1,"yyyy-MM-dd") +"]")`

The first solution throws an error stating 'unknown function FORMAT' and the error in the second solution reads '"VBAMDX.NOW()" is expecting a single parameter "index"'. Same goes for VBAMDX.FORMAT if I replace VBAMDX.NOW with only NOW.
But all pages explaining VBAMDX have two parameters for FORMAT and none for NOW...

Comment: check LookupByKey function that is a better alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is because Excel FORMAT is not supported (error reporting has been improved in the latest version of icCube). Instead I would use the functions as mentionned in this [page](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Java%20Functions.php):

```
StrToMember( "[Time].[Calendar].[Day].&["+ DateToString( NOW()-1,"yyyy-MM-dd") +"]")
```

---

But in icCube you've [LookupByKey](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/LookupByKey.php) function that is a more robust solution if your key is a date :

```
LookupByKey( [Time].[Calendar].[Day],  Now() )
```

or if you need a date :

```
LookupByKey( [Time].[Calendar].[Day],  Today() )
```

You can easily navigate dates with functions ([doc](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_types/dateandtime.php)).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `-1` causing the error of `NOW`?

So maybe the following, which deleted the `-1` and adds a single `LAG`, would work?

```
STRTOMEMBER("[date].[date].[day].["+ VBAMDX.FORMAT(VBAMDX.NOW(),"yyyy-MM-dd") +"]").LAG(1)
```

---

I just noticed that you're missing,  in your code, an ampersand in front of the square bracket of the last section of the member name, so please try one of the following:

```
STRTOMEMBER("[date].[date].[day].&["+ FORMAT(NOW()-1,"yyyy-MM-dd") +"]")
```

or

```
STRTOMEMBER("[date].[date].[day].&["+ VBAMDX.FORMAT(VBAMDX.NOW()-1,"yyyy-MM-dd") +"]")
```

---

If you try these 3 measures do they both fail?

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today1] AS 
    VBAMDX.NOW() 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today2] AS 
    VBAMDX.NOW()-1
  MEMBER [Measures].[Today3] AS 
    VBAMDX.FORMAT(VBAMDX.NOW()-1,"yyyy-MM-dd")
...
```

Comment: Still the same error: "syntax error: the implicit Item() function call (applied to:syntax error: the implicit Item() function call (applied to:VBAMDX.NOW) is expecting a single (index) parameter: got no parameter.) is expecting a single (index) parameter: got no parameter."  --  And in addition, if today's member doesn't exist, lag() doesn't help...

Comment: @UlrichWuenstel I think you may be missing an `&` symbol from your code - see addition to my answer

Comment: Unfortunately this has nothing to do with the problem. The error states, that the funciton VBAMDX.NOW() needs a parameter, but I wouldn't know, what. It seems to be an IcCube inherent problem.